# How do I remove background tv music?

Tags: audio, music, recording, audacity, voice

I have an audio recording of a recent meeting, the stupid thing I did was leave the TV on MTV. Now listening to the recording the music is more dominant than the actual speech and vocals. Is there a way to eliminate the TV music or reduce it and make the vocals louder. 
**If it helps I can identify music playing in the background

Comment: What you describe isn't easily complished without special hardware

Comment: No special software can be used? Paid or free. Windows or Mac.

Comment: @Wesley If your audio have TV noise only for couple of seconds(that is no actual voice you want to preserve), then it's very easy to remove the same noise print from entire audio clip using ADOBE AUDITION cs5 [see video tutorial](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/cs-55-production-premium-feature-tour-/whats-new-in-audition-cs55/) see from 04:00 in this video.

Comment: @Wesley - I am unable to provide software recomendations on this website.  As I indicated.  Its possible but this is normally done with audio equipment.

Answer (score 0):

If this is throughout the clip, you cannot do this without tremendously specialized work (read expensive).